# Is there a Python library function which attempts to guess the character-encoding of some bytes?

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, invalid-characters

I'm writing some mail-processing software in Python that is encountering strange bytes in header fields.  I suspect this is just malformed mail; the message itself claims to be us-ascii, so I don't think there is a true encoding, but I'd like to get out a unicode string approximating the original one without throwing a `UnicodeDecodeError`.

So, I'm looking for a function that takes a `str` and optionally some hints and does its darndest to give me back a `unicode`.  I could write one of course, but if such a function exists its author has probably thought a bit deeper about the best way to go about this.

I also know that Python's design prefers explicit to implicit and that the standard library is designed to avoid implicit magic in decoding text. I just want to explicitly say "go ahead and guess".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the standard library doesn't have a function, though it's not too difficult to write one as suggested above.  I think the real thing I was looking for was a way to decode a string and guarantee that it wouldn't throw an exception.  The errors parameter to string.decode does that.

```
def decode(s, encodings=('ascii', 'utf8', 'latin1')):
    for encoding in encodings:
        try:
            return s.decode(encoding)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            pass
    return s.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: You could skip the `'ascii'` case at the end and just use `latin1`, since `latin1` will decode all 256 byte values without error.

Answer (score 28):

+1 for the [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) module.

It is not in the standard library, but you can easily install it with the following command:

```
$ pip install chardet
```

[Example](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-using-the-detect-function):

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> rawdata = urllib.request.urlopen('http://yahoo.co.jp/').read()
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(rawdata)
{'encoding': 'EUC-JP', 'confidence': 0.99}
```

See [Installing Pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/) if you don't have one.

Comment: Didn't it strike you that `ISO-8859-2` was a nonsense?

Comment: @John Machin: Yes, it was. It is educational to show that you should not blindly trust it. Current results are different ('utf-8' and 'ascii' correspondingly).

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/chardet/

Comment: why is it nonsense? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this that I've found is to iteratively try decoding a prospective with each of the most common encodings inside of a try except block.