# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 3: invalid continuation byte

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, database-migration, inspectdb

I'm writing the Django React application and I have a huge existing database. I created models using 'inspectdb' command...

My database is a bit old and it is full of Croatian characters because of it models couldn't be created.

Is there any line of code that could solve a complete issue with this chararacter set on Django side?

Comment: I think you may find this Q&A useful. It seems like the next logical step, but isn't technically a duplicate yet. https://stackoverflow.com/a/16771912/1637351

Comment: I created everything inside my project regulary. The only thing that is making me issue is that I have legacy databases that I need to use. I need an solution that will care abount encoding inside the project. Thank you!