# Read file with Python without knowing encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, readfile

I want to read all files from a folder (with `os.walk`) and convert them to one encoding (UTF-8). The problem is those files don't have same encoding. They could be UTF-8, UTF-8 with BOM, UTF-16.

Is there any way to do read those files without knowing their encoding?

Comment: In the most general sense, no. But you can use various heuristics to have a good go at it, it's very dependant on your specific data set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read those files in binary mode.  Also, [the chardet library](https://github.com/chardet/chardet) can help you detect character encoding. Using chardet, you can detect the encoding of your files and decode the data you get. Though this module has limitations.

As an example:

```
from chardet import detect

with open('your_file.txt', 'rb') as ef:
    detect(ef.read())
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey. That does help.

Answer (score 0):

**If** it is indeed always one of these 3 then it is easy. If you can read the file using UTF-8 then it is *probably* UTF-8. Otherwise it will be UTF-16. Python can also automatically discard the BOM if present.

You can use a try ... except block to try both:

```
try:
    tryToConvertMyFile(from, to, 'utf-8-sig')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    tryToConvertMyFile(from, to, 'utf-16')
```

If other encodings are present as well (like ISO-8859-1) then forget it, there is no 100% reliable way of figuring out the encoding. But you can guess—see for example [Is there a Python library function which attempts to guess the character-encoding of some bytes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269060/is-there-a-python-library-function-which-attempts-to-guess-the-character-encodin)

Comment: @ClaytonWahlstrom yes, that is also what the linked question says. But for this simple case it is not necessary.